# Recursion with nested array with hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm not getting this to work correctly.

I have an array of hashes with a nested arrays of hashes of varying depth. If any of the nested results are false it must return false otherwise true.

```
array = [
  {
    result: true,
    dependents: [
      {
        result: true,
        dependents: [
          {result: true},
          {result: false}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  result: true,
  dependents: []
]

def result(array)
   if array.find {|line| line[:result] == false}
    return false
   else
    array.each do |line| 
      result(line[:dependents])
    end
  end
  true    
end

result(array)
#=> true (should be false)
```

The method `result()` is not working correctly at the moment as it is returning true for the given array and should be false. Any ideas?

Comment: It helps people answering you if you break-down complex data into something that fits into the default code display width. The more readable your question is, the easier it is for others to understand, and the faster they can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursively calling the `result` method but you aren't breaking when the result of that call returns false.

```
def result(array)
  array.each do |h|
    return false if h[:result] == false
    return false if h[:dependents] && result(h[:dependents]) == false
  end

  true
end
```

Comment: You might consider showing your code returns the correct values for one array where it should return true and another for where it should return false.  I prefer `key?` to checking if a hash value is `nil`, as `nil` values are permitted.

Comment: Thanks, works and I found I could extend your solution easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
  result(line[:dependents])
```

Probably must be

```
  return false if not result(line[:dependents])  ## Or unless ...
```

Or perhaps simply

```
  result(line[:dependents]) or return false
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, just found @fbonetti answer easier to extend.